# Encode a barcode with a string output

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, zxing

I've been trying encode a CODE 39 barcode into image with a string output like a picture below. I set PureBarcode = false, but the output was just a barcode without string. Thanks for any helps

[image]

```
 barcodewritter = new BarcodeWriter
                  {
                    Format = ZXing.BarcodeFormat.CODE_39,
                    Options = new ZXing.Common.EncodingOptions
                    {
                        Height = 100,
                        Width = 500,
                        Margin = 30,
                        PureBarcode=false
                    }
                  };
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Thanks for posting an image of the desired output. Can you post a screenshot of what's actually generated by your code?

Comment: It actually generated a CODE 39 barcode with image(pure barcode) without a content "CODE 39" below like picture above.

Answer (score 0):

ZXing.Net for Windows Phone doesn't support the output of the barcode content below the image. It is only implemented for Windows Forms and for the barcode types EAN-8 and EAN-13.
If you want the output which is shown in your sample you have to add the text to the image yourself (f.e. implementing the IRenderer interface and use it with the BarcodeWriter).

Comment: Thanks you, I got it